# OpenCTI methods executed in User or System mode?

Tags: opencti

I was investigating how OpenCTI handles DML when methods like "saveLog()" are called. Since the OpenCTI libs are loaded via `opencti_min.js` or `interaction.js` (lex or classic) on the iframe loaded by a User, every operation run when calling the OpenCTI API should strictly run in User mode, since no apex is involved (as soon as runApex() method is used, which then would allow the apex class to set the security level).

I couldn't find anything specifically mentioned in Salesforce docs (not even in PDFs or release notes docs), so I am unsure how OpenCTI calls are handled by Salesforce, if they are run in User or System mode (or if they have their own different way).

I made some tests with the Task object and verified that if I remove the field-security level "visible" access for a field to a User, whatever I was trying to store in that field doesn't get stored, but the operation still runs successfully, even if a SOQL query to the field would return `No such column 'Field' on entity 'ObjectName'`. If I add a permission set where the field has "read" permission but not "edit", I am still able to store a value in the field.

Everything seems to lead to the conclusion that OpenCTI operations run in User mode, but I wanted to check if anyone could give a better overview on this topic.

Comment: Which JS method are you invoking that is giving you a permissions error?

Comment: Probably I wasn't too clear, but nothing is returning a permission error, since, as I mentioned, I am able to call "saveLog" trying to store data in a non visible field and the operation runs successfully, even if the value in the non visible field is not stored. My question is if OpenCTI api calls are run in User or System mode on Salesforce side.

Comment: Would you be able to show a screenshot of the Chrome Dev Console showing the error being thrown and the line of code where it happens?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is not related to an error being thrown, but how OpenCTI methods are run in Salesforce...

Comment: I understand, and I want to try and help maybe understand the context they are running in, but I am wondering if you could show when the error is occurring?

Comment: I'm not sure you do, there's no error mentioned, the question is if anyone knows how OpenCTI requests are run on Salesforce side.